# Python Loop While Until Condition Is Met

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to create a while or if loop to step through sequentially a list to return the number of steps needed until the value changes. Here is a sample of my list. For the first items (through the 47), the loop would put out 1. For the first 39, the loop would put out 3, for the second 39 it would put out 2, for the third it would put out 1. Then for the first 31 it would put 5, then for the next 31 it would put 4, etc.

I am not exactly sure how to do this and if it can be done using a while loop. I think it might be able to be done with an iterator/counter that starts at 1, and then steps up (+= 1) until the value changes. I think it would be a 'while list[orig index] == list[orig + iterator index], iterate the counter and test whether equal. That said, I don't know how while loops could again assess the original true condition with the new 'iterator' value.

I tried something like this, which seems to work but is definitely clunky... any thoughts on how to simplify. It also does not account for counts above the number of nested 'ifs'

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    diff = 1
    if df.iloc[i + diff - 1]['prev_count'] != '3--2':
        gap.append(diff)
    else:
        diff += 1
        if df.iloc[i + diff - 1]['prev_count'] != '3--2':
            gap.append(diff)
        else:
            diff += 1
            if df.iloc[i + diff - 1]['prev_count'] != '3--2':
                gap.append(diff)
            else:
                diff += 1
                if df.iloc[i + diff - 1]['prev_count'] != '3--2':
                    gap.append(diff)
                else:
                    diff += 1
                    gap.append(diff)
```

> list1 = [[81,
> 79,
> 74,
> 57,
> 47,
> 39,
> 39,
> 39,
> 31,
> 31,
> 31,
> 31,
> 31,
> 30,
> 27,
> 22,
> 20,

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't write code for you.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you already tried and where are you stuck exactly? If you're not sure how to start, try writing out the instructions on paper first. Also, please write a proper title. [ask] has tips on that.

Comment: I would probably write a generator function, but you should go ahead and post your implementation in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tried to add a bit more detail. I got this working with a very manual approach with nested IFs, although it is limited to the number of IF statements I wrote in. I am wondering if there is a way to do use while, or iterate through the same If step until a condition is met. Cheers and thanks for all of your help (and patience with the question - new to coding and Stack Overflow!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a numpy array to iterate the conditions. For example:

```py
#Array to check
x = np.array([81, 79, 74, 57, 47, 39, 39, 39, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 27, 22, 20])
#Counts
y = np.ones(x.shape)

#Loop for each gap, check for equality, and add to y
for i in range(1, x.shape[0]):
    y[:-i] = np.where(x[:-i]==x[i:], y[:-i]+1, y[:-i])
print(y)
```

which should yield:

```py
>>> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 3. 2. 1. 5. 4. 3. 2. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

There are many other ways to do this so you can explore other options too.

Comment: It's really bad to use loops while using `numpy`. Try to replace them with some kind of `numpy` methods if you are able

Comment: @mathfux I can think of using list comprehension and `np.sum` to avoid the for-loop but then the code would be too abstract and hard to understand for beginners.

Comment: In terms of performance list comprehension and for-loops are both equivalent. It's good idea to replace them with some `numpy` methods. However, using `np.where` for each item is overkill. Don't try to run it on large lists that contain a single repeated item.

Comment: Assuming `np.where` is at O(n) complexity, then the code I made will be O(n**2). I know that this is not the best way to do this task but I know it is the easiest one to do.

Comment: Can this be done with a while loop?